# Web Api 2 Exception Filter and Global Handling

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api2, actionfilterattribute

i have a custom ExceptionFilterAttribute in place that almost logs anything that gets thrown in a controller. Almost means that there are circumstances where this filter does not handle exceptions. This is where there is now a custom service that implements the IExceptionLogger interface that handles everything. This is where it gets messy.

Both handle the exception creating duplicate logs. The Attribute is prefered since it contains more custom information (dependency injected).

Is there any built in way to mark the exception as handled in order to avoid the service if the filter is used?

Is there any other way to catch only the exceptions that the filter did not handle?